# SBT fails to launch on ARM64 Apple silicon with error Could not find required component 'xsbti'

Tags: sbt, arm64, apple-silicon

When I launch **SBT** 1.5 using the command which in turn launches version 0.13 for the project

```
❯ sbt -v
[sbt_options] declare -a sbt_options='()'
[process_args] java_version = '8'
# Executing command line:
java
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-Xss4M
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
-jar
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sbt/1.5.0/libexec/bin/sbt-launch.jar

[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/viswanath/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Updating {file:/Users/viswanath/.sbt/0.13/plugins/}global-plugins...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
```

I get the following error

```
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) sbt.InvalidComponent: Could not find required component 'xsbti'
```

on my MacBookPro with M1 processor (a.k.a Apple silicon) on ARM64 architecture. Any clue on how to fix this problem?

Note: Bundled SBT runs fine on IntelliJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bumped up the project's SBT version to 1.5.0 and the problem disappeared. [See this githib issue for more information](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/6162#issuecomment-734960337).

Alternatively, [check this workaround](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/6447#issuecomment-822102167) on SBT 1.5.0 for launching SBT in interactive mode.

```
sbt -Dsbt.boot.directory=/tmp/boot1 -Dsbt.launcher.coursier=false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try installing with [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/)

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash

source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"

sdk install java

sdk install sbt

sbt compile
```

Comment: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/12246